# Codigniter replace dots in my input names with underscores

Tags: codeigniter, validation, codeigniter-2

When I submit a form, Codigniter replace input names containing dots (.) with underscores (_). Here is a simple example:

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="text" name="client.firstname" />
    <input type="text" name="client.lastname" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

`$_POST` contains now:

```
Array
(
    [client_firstname] => xxxxx
    [client_lastname] => yyyyy
)
```

So `client.firstname` became `client_firstname` with no reason?!

Do you have any idea of what is happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is not CI doing this, but PHP itself – and it is a remnant of the “olden days” before there were $_POST/$_GET/etc., when external parameters where imported into the global variable scope directly; because variable names can not contain a `.` in PHP, because that is also the concatenation operator.

And this is documented as well, http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php:

> **Note:**
>   Dots and spaces in variable names are converted to underscores. For example `<input name="a.b" />` becomes $_REQUEST["a_b"].